# Blackjack missing algorithm

Tags: blackjack, gambling

In the midst of finishing up my Black Jack application. So I'm currently bug-testing and about 1 in 20 tries I'll come across a scenario where It deals the dealer's cards, but that's all it does. Then the hand ends. For some reason It seems to not be meeting a valid if condition to run through. Here is the algorithm I used. Please tell me if you find any outcome/algorithm I might possibly be missing.

```
if(HitOrStand.equals("Stand")) {
        // if user stands, we know need to focus on the dealer's hand
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        //Deal dealers first 2 cards
        String dCard1 = dealCard();
        String dCard2 = dealCard();
        //Get value of dealers first 2 cards.
        int dValue1 = getCardValue(dCard1);
        int dValue2 = getCardValue(dCard2);

        //dTotal is the total value of the dealers hand. So we add card1 and card2 to dTotal
        int dTotal = dValue1 + dValue2;
        System.out.println("Dealer hand is a "+dCard1+","+dCard2);

        //Check if dealer hand is greater then player hand, and also less then 21.
        if ((dTotal) > (pTotal) && (dTotal) <= 21) {
            System.out.println("YOU LOST! The dealer's hand was a "+dCard1+","+dCard2+"(Total:"+dTotal+") You've lost $"+bet);
        }
        //If dealer is less than player hand and less then 21, let the dealer deal himself another card.
        else if((dTotal) <= (pTotal) && (dTotal) < 21) {
            //deal 3rd card
            String dCard3 = dealCard();
            int dValue3 = getCardValue(dCard3);
            //Add value of card3 to dTotal
            dTotal += dValue3;

            //Check if 3rd card made dealer bust
            if(dTotal > 21) {
                System.out.println("Dealer draws a......."+dCard3);
                System.out.println("YOU WIN!!! Dealer drew a "+dCard3+" and BUSTED! Congrats you've won $"+bet * 2);
                balance += (bet * 2);
            }
            //Check if dealer hand is greater then player hand, and also less then 21.
            else if((dTotal) > (pTotal) && (dTotal) <= 21) {
                        System.out.println("Dealer draws a......."+dCard3);
                        System.out.println("YOU LOST! The dealer's hand was a "+dCard1+","+dCard2+","+dCard3+".(Total:"+dTotal+") You've lost $"+bet);
            }
            //If dealer is less than player hand and less then 21, let the dealer deal himself another card.
            else if((dTotal) <= (pTotal) && (dTotal) < 21) {
                    //deal 4th card
                    String dCard4 = dealCard();
                    int dValue4 = getCardValue(dCard4);
                    //Add value of card4 to dTotal
                    dTotal += dValue4;

                        if(dTotal > 21) {
                            System.out.println("Dealer draws a......."+dCard4);
                            System.out.println("YOU WIN!!! Dealer drew a "+dCard4+" and BUSTED! Congrats you've won $"+bet * 2);
                            balance += (bet * 2);
                        }
                        //Check if dealer hand is greater then player hand, and also less then 21.
                        else if((dTotal) > (pTotal) && (dTotal) <= 21) {
                                System.out.println("Dealer draws a......."+dCard4);
                                System.out.println("YOU LOST! The dealer's hand was a "+dCard1+","+dCard2+","+dCard3+","+dCard4+".(Total:"+dTotal+") You've lost $"+bet);
                            }
               } 
        }
   }
```

Comment: What does your code do if the dealer is dealt two more cards yet their total is less than the player's total? For example, if the player had 10 + 10 and the dealer started with 2 + 3 and then was dealt 4 and 5. The dealer could in theory draw 11 cards (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + ...), so your current code structure may need some rethinking.

Comment: @Blender Is that whats happening? I only went up to 3 or 4 cards for the dealer.